# Cast an object dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I have an abstract class `Entity` with several subclasses: `SubclassA`, `SubclassB`, and `SubclassA` has a subclass `SubSubClass`.

I also have an object `someObject` of class `SomeClass` that looks like this:

```
class SomeClass{
    void doSomething(Entity e){..}
    void doSomething(SubclassA e){..}
    void doSomething(SubclassB e){..}
    void doSomething(SubSubClass e){..}
}
```

I have a `List<Entity> list`. Every item in this list is passed into `someObject.doSomething`.

```
for(Entity entity : list){
    someObject.doSomething(entity);
}
```

Thing is, `doSomething(Entity e)` is always invoked, no matter what the actual type of the current `Entity` is, because the reference type is always `Entity`. To fix this, I need to do casting, like: `someObject.doSomething((SubclassB)entity)`.

So I was wondering if there's a way to cast an object dynamically to whatever concrete type it is, without `instanceof` operations.

If there is no way to do this, how would you deal with my situation?

Answer (score 5):

Flip it, add a `receiveWork` (or whatever you want to name it) method (that possibly expects a `Runnable` or other executable unit) to `Entity` and its subclasses and invoke that method in your foreach loop. Let polymorphism do the work for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself tempted to cast an object you have probably already done something wrong.

Your mistake is expecting to write code that does something with an object - instead you should teach the object how to do it itself. This is a central tenet of oop.

See how simple that can be:

```
class Entity {

    public void action(SomeClass c) {
        c.doSomething(this);
    }
}

class SubclassA extends Entity {

    public void action(SomeClass c) {
        c.doSomething(this);
    }
}

class SubclassB extends Entity {

    public void action(SomeClass c) {
        c.doSomething(this);
    }
}

class SubSubClass extends SubclassA {

    public void action(SomeClass c) {
        c.doSomething(this);
    }
}

class SomeClass {

    void doSomething(Entity e) {
        System.out.println("Do something (Entity) with an " + e.getClass());
    }

    void doSomething(SubclassA e) {
        System.out.println("Do something (SubclassA) with an " + e.getClass());
    }

    void doSomething(SubclassB e) {
        System.out.println("Do something (SubclassB) with an " + e.getClass());
    }

    void doSomething(SubSubClass e) {
        System.out.println("Do something (SubSubClass) with an " + e.getClass());
    }
}

public void test() {
    List<Entity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Entity());
    list.add(new SubclassA());
    list.add(new SubclassB());
    list.add(new SubSubClass());
    SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
    for (Entity entity : list) {
        entity.action(someObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would write one singular `doSomething(Entity e)` function, then within that determine the subclass using `instanceof`. I'm sorry I can't offer a solution to your problem which avoids instanceof. Without knowing more information about your project, that seems to me like it would be a simple enough solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should use Visitor pattern here. Take a look on this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern for details.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a violation of OO principles.

Why are these methods not delegated to the sub class?

By attaching doSomething to the Entity and overriding it, my methods in this Someclass, can simply delegate, getting an entity and calling the entity.doSomething(). That will automatically call the right method. Through polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I don't know if this is what you want, but since you don't want to use instanceof, I'd personally cast all of the Entities down to the lowest subclass and have your `doSomething` method throw exceptions if it receives the wrong object. Then, when an exception is thrown, I'd catch it. In the catch block, I'd pass the same object (casted up one level) to the method.

```
for(Entity entity : list){
   try {
      doSomething((SubSubclass)entity);
   } catch (SomeException e) {
      try {
         doSomething((SubClassA)entity); //I believe that this throws a ClassCastException of the object is actually a SubClassB...
      } catch (SomeException e) {
         try {
            //etc. etc...
```

Again, I don't know if this is what you'd want, and this uses a bunch of nested try catch blocks, but it's still a solution.